# CreateThread vs PsCreateSystemThread - What is the difference?

Tags: c++, c, driver, windows-kernel, createthread

I would like to ask what are the differences between `PsCreateSystemThread` and `CreateThread`. From MSDN description it seems to that `PsCreateSystemThread` is for Kernel Thread.

`CreateThread` seem like a kernel thread but share the same virtual space memory with a process. That mean I can have many thread running together BUT I cant access other process memory space.

Answer (score 2):

**CreateThread** creates a thread to execute within the virtual address space of the calling process, while **PsCreateSystemThread** creates a system thread that executes in kernel mode and returns a handle for the thread.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateThread` creates user mode thread that works in the address space of the process. It has nothing to do with kernel. This API is about 20 years old.

`PsCreateSystemThread` creates kernel thread.